# Flashing value to a <select> element in Play Framework

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

I'm aware that value of a 'select' element can't be set from the 'value' attribute but via putting a 'selected' attribute in 'option'.

I made a simple if-else block comparing the flash value to put a 'selected' attribute on the right 'option'.
But it didn't work and always went to the else block, even though the 'value' returned by the flash is correct (The 'value' of 'select' in the else block).

```
@if(flash.get("""value""") == "value3"){
    <select>
      <option value="value1">value1</option>
      <option value="value2">value2</option>
      <option value="value3" selected>value3</option>
    </select>
}
@if(flash.get("""value""").equals("value2")){
    <select>
      <option value="value1">value1</option>
      <option value="value2" selected>value2</option>
      <option value="value3">value3</option>
    </select>
} else{
    <select value="@flash.get("""value""")">
      <option value="value1" selected>value1</option>
      <option value="value2">value2</option>
      <option value="value3">value3</option>
    </select>
}
```

Is there actually a way to set  value with Play Framework flashing?

EDIT

So, I tried using the custom helper blesior written.

```
@myOwnOptionHelper(optionValue: String, optionLabel: String) = {
    <option value = "@optionValue"
    @if(flash.get("""flashValue""") != null && flash.get("""flashValue""") == optionValue) { selected = "selected" } >@optionLabel</option>
}
```

And the select element

```
<select>
  @myOwnOptionHelper("value1", "value1")
  @myOwnOptionHelper("value2", "value2")
  @myOwnOptionHelper("value3", "value3")
</select>
```

The result is, after flashing none of the option gets selected.
I tried rewritting the if block and displayed the flashvalue for the sake of testing.

```
@myOwnOptionHelper(optionValue: String, optionLabel: String) = {
    <option value = "@optionValue"
    @if(flash.get("""flashValue""").isDefined && "value2" == optionValue) { selected = "selected" } >@flash.get("""flashValue""") + @optionLabel</option>
}
```

And it worked. After flashing "value2" is selected and displayed the correct flashValue (ex: "value1 + value2"). I changed the "!= null" to ".isDefined" for testing because the value2 gets selected even though there is no flashing happening.

EDIT 2

Apparently flash.get("flashValue") is an [Option]. And that explains why it didn't trigger the right if-else block on the first place, because it returns a Some(value). By adding a match-case block, the custom helper works perfectly. Thanks to @blesior

```
@myOwnOptionHelper(optionValue: String, optionLabel: String) = {
    <option value = "@optionValue"
    @if(flash.get("flashValue").isDefined && (flash.get("flashValue") match {
      case Some(x:String) => x
      case _ => ""
    }) == optionValue) { selected = "selected" } >@optionLabel</option>
}
```

Comment: BTW, fix your question by adding version of Play as a tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hm, two mistakes:

- you are performing two blocks here - first is checking ***value3***, second is checking ***value2*** or else. That means, that if your value will be 3 you'll get TWO select fields
- Why do you repeat all options in all blocks?

Instead you can write custom *helper* for the `option` tag, which will generate it and  check flashed value against the value of option, you can do this even in the same view, although it would be better if it was done in tag template ([docs](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/ScalaTemplateUseCases))...

```
@myOwnOptionHelper(optionValue: String, optionLabel: String)={
    <option value="@optionValue"
        @if(flash.get("myFlashedValue") != null && flash.get("myFlashedValue")==optionValue) { selected="selected"} >@optionLabel</option>
}

<select name="someSelect">
    @myOwnOptionHelper("value1", "One")
    @myOwnOptionHelper("value2", "Two")
    @myOwnOptionHelper("value3", "Three")
    @myOwnOptionHelper("value4", "Four")
    <!-- ... -->
    @myOwnOptionHelper("value1000000", "Million")
</select>
```

Of course the helper can get other params i.e. if you don't want to pass the set value by flash, but reading it from some other model, etc.

Comment: Ah yes, my mistake.
I should have written another "if" for value1.
Was in a bit of hurry to test back then, so I just wrapped the entire select element with varying option selected inside the if block.

Gonna try this one for a bit, seems like I didn't read the documentation well enough to find custom helper.

Though I'm a bit curious, that code should work if the value is value2 right ? On my end it always went to the else part on every value. Thanks

Comment: Just copy my sample to the view, remember that the `@myOwnOptionHelper` declaration must be at beginning of doc (after view params BUT before layout block if used... that's the better solution

Comment: To be even more DRY, I'd consider using `map` over a collection of value/label pairs

Comment: @blesior I used the code you written, it didn't work even though the flashed value is right (I tried to display it by putting the flash.get on the optionLabel's place). See edit.